# Differences in Core-Text between ios 6 and ios 5.1?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, core-text

It appears there are some differences in the CoreText implementation between ios 5.1 and ios 6, as you can see from these two screenshots :

ios 6:
[image]

ios 5:
[image]

Firstly the text color isn't applied correctly. It seems that on ios 5.1 the `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName` requires that you give it a `CGColor`, whereas on ios 6, passing it a UIColor will suffice. So I solved the issue by changing my code to:

```
[attributes setObject:(id)[color CGColor] 
               forKey:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName];
```

Secondly, the paragraph spacing is a bit off. The distance between "sight" and "According" is 11px vs 25px (measured in the screenshot). In both cases paragraph spacing is set to 5:

```
NSMutableData *styleSettingsArray = [NSMutableData data];
CGFloat spaceBefore,spaceAfter;
...
CTParagraphStyleSetting styleSettingB = {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacingBefore   ,sizeof(CGFloat),&spaceBefore};
CTParagraphStyleSetting styleSettingA = {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierParagraphSpacing         ,sizeof(CGFloat),&spaceAfter};
[styleSettingsArray appendBytes:&styleSettingB length:sizeof(styleSettingB)];
[styleSettingsArray appendBytes:&styleSettingA length:sizeof(styleSettingA)];
...
if(styleSettingsArray.length > 0)
{
    CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyleRef = CTParagraphStyleCreate([styleSettingsArray bytes], [styleSettingsArray length] / sizeof(CTParagraphStyleSetting));
    [dictionary setObject:(__bridge id)(paragraphStyleRef) forKey:(NSString*)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName];
    CFRelease(paragraphStyleRef);
}
```

Description of `paragraphStyleRef` in console:

```
iOS 6:
CTParagraphStyle:
base writing direction = -1, alignment = 3, line break mode = 0, default tab interval = 0
first line head indent = 0, head indent = 0, tail indent = 0
line height multiple = 0, maximum line height = 0, minimum line height = 0
line spacing adjustment = 0, paragraph spacing = 5, paragraph spacing before = 5


iOS 5:

CTParagraphStyle:
writing direction = -1, alignment = 3, line break mode = 0, default tab interval = 0
first line head indent = 0, head indent = 0, tail indent = 0
line height multiple = 0, maximum line height = 0, minimum line height = 0
line spacing adjustment = 0, paragraph spacing = 5, paragraph spacing before = 5
```

which seem the same to me, so I don't know what the problem is. Other than the spacing between the paragraphs, they're identical.

So how can I fix this? Also are there any other things I should be aware of that might cause the text to display differently?

**EDIT:**
After some investigation, it turnes out that the difference in paragraph styling was actually caused by my line breaks which printed "\r\n". Changing that to "\n" solved the spacing problem.

Answer (score 7):

Core Text got an overhaul in iOS 6. You check out all the changes by watching the WWDC 2012 videos that are available for free if you have an Apple Developer Account.

So now in iOS 6, you can't use any of the low level Core Text attributes like kCTForegroundColorAttributeName or kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName.

Instead you use a **new set of high level attributes**, like NSForegroundColorAttributeName & NSParagraphStyle.

So your code would change to:

```
/*Note that you have use the Foundation class
  for the attribute value instead of it's Core-Foundation counterpart.*/

[attributes setObject:color 
           forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];

CGFloat spaceBefore, spaceAfter;

NSMutableParagraphStyle *mutableParagraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle];
mutableParagraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = spaceAfter;
mutableParagraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = spaceBefore;

[attributes setObject:mutableParagraphStyle 
           forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
```

You can find the documentation for the **all new attributes** here:
    http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: very useful information, +1 even though it doesn't answer the question .

Comment: Your question was how you could fix your code, and if there were other things that would cause your text to be displayed differently. Those other things are the new attributes, that's it. There are other differences in Core Text between iOS 5.1 to iOS 6, but they are only newly added API. What do you feel I left out?

Comment: both NSParagraphStyle and kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName yielded the same results on ios 6, but of course, you can't use NSParagraphStyle on ios 5. I pointed out what actually caused the problem in an edit to my question (which was kinda silly tbh -- I got my endlines mixed-up between unix/windows), and I also awarded you the bounty since your answer is useful, but I didn't accept the answer since the problem was caused by something unrelated...

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for the bounty anyway.